открытие selenium браузера с профилем
Пишу код, и застрял на одном месте. Я хочу запустить драйвер с нужным мне профилем chrome и указываю путь. Он запускается и после открытия просто замирает на месте, как будто что-то выполняет. Если использовать обычный webdriver, то окно открывается и через секунд 5 закрывается с ошибкой, если использовать undetected chromedriver, то оно открывается и просто ничего не происходит. Вот код:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
    
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\dansa\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) 
    
driver.get('https://example.com/')

Просто открывается главная страница и все, а example.com почему-то не открывается

если запускать через webdriver то вот ошибка
(не знаю как тут скрины грузить короче вот )
https://imgur.com/a/v2U2SJ0

вы понимаете, что это не ошибка, а запрос отключить адблокер на этом сайте?

@strawdog у меня нет адблокера
